# Counterexamples of second mean value theorem of integral

Tags: calculus, analysis

Recently I am having trouble understanding [Bonnet's mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Second_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals). I looked back and forth on the proof, and find that the condition of $\phi$ being decreasing is essential. However, I am unable to find an example to illustrate how the theorem fails when $\phi$ is NOT decreasing.

Can anyone give an example?

Answer (score -1):

DO NOT LEAVE a comment before even reading the question. The question is asking for an example where the theorem FAILS. It is NOT asking for an example where the theorem applies properly. It is irresponsible to vote or comment before even understanding the question properly.

Let $\phi(x)=x$, $G(x)=1$, and $[a,b]=[0,1]$. Then
$$
\int_0^1 G(x)\phi(x)dx=0.5
$$

But for any $c\in[0,1]$, 
$$
\phi(0) \int_0^c G(x)dx=0.
$$
So the theorem fails.

Comment: This is not correct since for increasing $\phi$, the second mean value needs $\phi(1)$ and then the result holds with $c=.5$

Comment: @Conrad DO NOT LEAVE a comment before even reading the question. The question is asking for an example where the theorem FAILS. It is NOT asking for an example where the theorem applies properly.

Comment: Your answer is wrong, the theorem doesn't fail in this case and that was my comment - just that the answer is not correct, not about a counterexample since that is tricky given that you didn't state exactly the conditions for failure  - the theorem appropriately phrased holds for bv functions in general, while for monotone functions again gotta be careful how to state it as it differs when function increasing, decreasing, positive or not, so obviously counterexample to wrongly stated theorem are incorrect

Comment: Yes — the form of Bonnet’s MVT specialized for a decreasing function is shown here not to hold by choosing this $\phi$ as an increasing function. The more general form for $\phi$ either monotone increasing or decreasing still holds: $$\int_0^1 \phi(x)G(x)\, dx = \\ \phi(0)\int_0^c G(x)\, dx + \phi(1)\int_c^1 G(x) \, dx$$ Both question and answer should not have been downvoted (+1)